# Where did this variable come from? Python

Tags: python, variables

Here's the source code for Hangman.This is from the book invent games with python.

```
words = 'ant baboon badger bat bear beaver camel cat clam cobra cougar coyote crow deer       dog donkey duck eagle ferret fox frog goat goose hawk lion lizard llama mole monkey moose   mouse mule newt otter owl panda parrot pigeon python rabbit ram rat raven rhino salmon seal shark sheep skunk sloth snake spider stork swan tiger toad trout turkey turtle weasel whale wolf wombat zebra'.split()

def getRandomWord(wordList):
    # This function returns a random string from the passed list of strings.
    wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1)
    return wordList[wordIndex]
```

Now,where did he get the variable wordList?There's only the variable words here!

Comment: it's a parameter to the function `getRandomWord`. It could be called `foo`, or anything else

Comment: As a side note, that's a strange way of getting a random sample from a list. After all, there's `random.choice()`...

Comment: The magic words are: `function parameter`

Comment: The code in question is on page 134 of the PDF of the book available free on the website, corresponding to page 108 of the physical book. The relevant concept was explained in detail on page 96/70 respectively. I have voted to close because it is OP's responsibility to actually pay attention to the reference material from which s/he is learning. It is not fair to others to skip ahead without understanding things, and then expect SO to clear up the more serious confusion that results later.

Comment: The code for the function is also specifically explained on page 147/121 (after talking about all the other concepts introduced earlier on in the Hangman code).

Answer (score 2):

It's from right here:

```
def getRandomWord(wordList):
```

When the `getRandomWord` function is called with an argument, such as `getRandomWord(words)`, the local variable `wordList` will be bound to refer to that argument.

Comment: `words` is already a list, please see at the end of string, function `.split()` is already called.

Comment: @anuragal: Oh, huh, it is. Should've scrolled right (and that list should've been constructed in a way that didn't involve a nearly 400-character line).

Answer (score 0):

In the `def`inition of the function `getRandomWord()`, `wordList` is defined as the (sole, mandatory) parameter that is passed to the function.

So if you pass a list to it, that list object is bound to the local name `wordList`, and the function can operate on it.

Answer (score 0):

`wordList` is just a parameter to the function `getRandomWord`. It doesn't have to match anything else, and in fact, is probably clearer that it doesn't.

Somewhere else in the code, it is probably invoking the function like this: `getRandomWord(words)`

Answer (score 0):

wordList is the parameter of the function!!! So when you call `getRandomWord(words)`  with `words` as parameter, then `words` become `wordList`!. Simple. But if you still have any confusion have a look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)